# Django: returning __str__ error when I try to add new instance of model from admin dashboard

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I try to add a new instance of any model that has `Campus` as a foreign key, I get this error, and I'm dumbfounded.

[image: error message]

Here is the code for the Campus model

```
from django.db import models

class Campus(models.Model):
name = models.TextField(max_length = 100, default=None)
description = models.TextField(max_length = 100, default=None)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I'm not sure what the problem is with the **str** function as this is what I do for all of my basic models.

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: It is not the `__str__` of the `Campus`, it is some other model that has as `__str__` something that returns a `Campus` object (likely with a `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField`), and thus does not call `__str__` on that object.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the `__str__` of the `Campus` that is the problem here. It is some other model (or something else) that has as `__str__` something that **returns a `Campus`** object (likely with a `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField`), and thus does not call `__str__` on that object.

So that normally happens if you have a model that looks like:

```
class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    campus = models.ForeignKey(Campus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.campus
```

Here the `__str__` method thus returns a `Campus` object, not a string. You can fix it by convertin the `Campus` object to a `str`ing, for example by calling `str(..)` on it:

```
class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    campus = models.ForeignKey(Campus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.campus)
```

Comment: Or you could just use **self.campus.name**